# Exception thrown in an iframe

Tags: asp.net, exception, iframe

How can I find whether an exception is thrown in an iframe or the page itself?
(In `Global.asax` page and in `Application_Error` method and of course in C#!)

Is there any way at all?

Comment: How in the world is global.asax going to add an iFrame to the page?

Comment: What?
I mean: An exception has been thrown. How can I find in `Application_Error` that the exception is in page that it is loaded in an iframe? I don't know Could I clear up my question?

Comment: global.asax doesn't have anything to do with iFrame. Can you load the frame into a separate page, so you can examine one page at a time, without the complication of frames?

Comment: You know. In fact, I want to change the default error page according to the place of error (page or iframe).

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't very clear at all. I'm sorry.

Comment: I wish I could help, but my frame of mind right now can't wrap itself around your problem. I think you're debugging the wrong thing.

Comment: I have a page that contains an iframe.
Now an exception has been thrown. How can I find that the exception was thrown in the page itself or in the page that is in the iframe?

Comment: You load the page for the iframe by itself. You don't load it in a frame. an exception gets thrown on the server, not in html.

Comment: Ok, I know.
In `global.asax` in `Application_Error` method,
how can I know the exception that has been thrown, is in a page that be loaded in an iframe or not?
I.e. I have division by zero exception, it is in server-side, but in the code of what page? the page that is loaded in frame?

Comment: Are you wanting to detect when an iframe has loaded a page that has had an exception occur? You can't.

Comment: Oh, thank you.
So that's impossible.
Tnx btw.

Comment: Again. I explain the problem in another way. Maybe there is a way ):.
I have a page that contains an iframe.
If an exception has been thrown in the page itself, I want to redirect the response the a page like defError.aspx, but if the exception is in iframe, I want to load the smallError.aspx in the iframe.

Comment: You can try, I haven't given up entirely as you see ;-)

Comment: I didn't know you did an edit.

Comment: You would not have anyway to know on the server that you were being loaded into an iframe when an exception occurred. You would have to always redirect on all errors.

Comment: In the web.config, `<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Error.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">`

Comment: Ok. Thank you again.
I give up now :)

Comment: If you have two different pages, and the throw is inside the page, you capture the error of each page, inside the pages, and you redirect them to different error page. If you ask for javascript error is a different way,